# SAS SGPLOT Meaningful names for charts with by statement

Tags: graphics, sas, naming, ods, sgplot

I refer here to the the issue addressed 6 years ago in "SAS GRAPH and multiple charts, more meaningful names?" To me this issue needs a solution. I need to generate one chart by indicator (2) and country (27). The index is 1,3,5,7,9,...,107. Please  try to find the file/worksheet (png/xls) for country x and indicator y. Good luck! Can somebody help me? Maybe the person who addressed the issue at that time found a solution (I really hope it)? Many thanks!

Below you have an example using sashelp library. It creates Picture1.png, Picture3.png and Picture5.png. Instead of this, I would like to have PictureIBM.png, PictureIntel.png and PictureMicrosoft.png.

```
proc sort data=SASHELP.STOCKS out=testfile; by stock date; run;
data testfile; set testfile;
by stock  ;
retain n;
if first.stock then n=0; else n=n+1;
if n le 5;
run;


ods listing gpath='write the path' ;
ods listing /*style = styles.new_font   */
    gpath='/ec/prod/1eusilc/flashestimates/FLIPI/3_Output/FE/PERFORMANCE/overall 2022/TIME SERIES' ;


ods graphics on / 
      width=14in height=10in
      outputfmt=gif
      imagemap=on
      imagename="Picture"
      border=off  reset=index ;


proc sgplot data=testfile noborder noopaque nowall  dattrmap=DATTRMAP  
title "write the title";
by stock ;
highlow x=date low=low high=high / type=bar   ;
scatter x=date y=close   ;
xaxis type=discrete;
run;
```

Comment: I have added an answer to the original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949236/sas-graph-and-multiple-charts-more-meaningful-names/74057505#74057505)

Comment: Thank you but I do not understand how can I adapt your solution to proc sgplot.  I use ods listing; ods graphics and proc sgplot. In sgplot I have two highlow statements and 1 scatter statement.

Comment: You don't show your code or an example or the issue. A solution mentioned in the linked post is to use macro's which gets around this entirely.

Comment: I can not copy/paste SAS code as the text is too long (even simplified))

Comment: You can make a simplified example of the issue using a data set from sashelp.

Comment: And I never said "there is no reason to have specific names", I said, " I've fortunately never had a reason to have specific file names."

Comment: I will try to use sashelp and come back! I am sorry for keeping in mind only the second part of the phrase! I am really blocked (and nervous) with this issue that keep me far from other much more important issues. Many thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: FYI the reason I've never had to worry about the file names is because I usually put graphics straight from SAS into a Word/PPT/PDF document as necessary for reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to do this, one uses the #byval as indicated in the previous solution and which you used in title but not the file name for some reason.

First make fake data:

```
data prdsummary;
    set sashelp.prdsale;
    where year=1993 and (country="GERMANY" or country="CANADA") and region="EAST" 
        and division="CONSUMER" and
    (product="SOFA" or product="TABLE" or product="BED");
run;

proc sort data=prdsummary;
    by country;
run;
```

Then use #BYVAL. However, if you run this code multiple times, SAS does not overwrite the previous files, it adds a 1 to the filename instead. So you need to make sure that the files don't already exist. There may be an option to control this feature, I'm unsure at the moment.

```
ods listing gpath='/home/fkhurshed/Demo1/';
title 'Graph for #byval1';
ods graphics / imagename="Country #byval1";

proc sgplot data=prdsummary;
    by country;
    vbar prodtype / group=product response=actual groupdisplay=stack;
run;
```

A second workaround is to use a macro instead and control the name explicitly.

```
*explicitly control the names via macro looping;
ods listing gpath='/home/fkhurshed/Demo1/';


%macro generate_country_graph(country=);
    ods graphics / imagename="Graphic for &Country.";

    proc sgplot data=prdsummary;
        where country="&country";
        vbar prodtype / group=product response=actual groupdisplay=stack;
    run;

%mend;

data _null_;
    set prdsummary;
    by country;

    if first.country then
        do;
            str=catt('%generate_country_graph(country=', country, ');');
            call execute(str);
        end;
run;
```

Comment: I feel so stupid! I've just tested the first solution (#byval) and it works perfectly ! Many, many thanks!